# How to use/enable kvm in amazon aws instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, kvm

I am not able to run VMs in amazon aws EC2 using kubevirt (currently using t2.large & c5.large instance type). The VMs always get stuck in Scheduling and gives the message: 0/2 nodes are available: 2 Insufficient devices.kubevirt.io/kvm.

```
$ sudo kvm-ok
INFO: Your CPU does not support KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can NOT be used
```

How can I enable KVM in amazon aws instances

Answer (score 6):

Nested virtualization is something that needs to be enabled on the hypervisor.

There's nothing you can do in your VM, if Amazon did not allow it at their level. I don't think EC2 offers that option. You may want to look for some hosting provider offering with dedicated servers.

Answer (score 4):

You can - on bare metal EC2 instances. However I was not successful with establishing direct network connection from the aws vpc subnet (or vpn) to the VMs deployed on the EC2 instance (I'm using ovs on EC2). From what I know you can only do it via NAT - if that's sufficient for you go for it. Here are the details: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-bare-metal-kvm-demo
Just note that bare metal EC2 instances are not cheap - like 4$ per hour.